# memory allocation of char array

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have following code:

```
Document document;
char *buf = new char[str.size()+1];
buf[str.size()] = '\0';
memcpy(buf, str.c_str(), str.size());
//string parsing
if (document.ParseInsitu<0>(buf).HasParseError()) {
    cerr << "Failed to parse string ";
}
delete[] buf;
```

When I check the program with valgrind I get this:

```
==29765== Invalid read of size 1
==29765==    at 0x402A682: bcmp (mc_replace_strmem.c:679)
==29765==  Address 0x49626a2 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 214 free'd
==29765==    at 0x402759B: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:409)

==29765== Invalid read of size 1
==29765==    at 0x402901A: strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:282)
==29765==    by 0x41ABE4A: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==29765==  Address 0x49626a8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 214 free'd
==29765==    at 0x402759B: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:409)

==29765== Invalid read of size 1
==29765==    at 0x4029D0E: memcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:635)
==29765==    by 0x41ABD15: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==29765==    by 0x41ABE65: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
==29765==    by 0x2C23: ???
==29765==  Address 0x49626b2 is 18 bytes inside a block of size 214 free'd
==29765==    at 0x402759B: operator delete[](void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:409)
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is json defined? it is the same as str?

Comment: `buf[json.size()] = '\0'; `is json.size() == str.size() ?

Comment: sorry, I was trying to make it more readable... that's the same variable

Comment: Can't see an error in the snipped. Can you give the signature of document.ParseInsitu<0>(buf), or try if it works if you comment out the if statement? I think the error is that the parser still uses buf, after the document.ParseInsitu<0>(buf) call.

Comment: it's from rapidjson library: http://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/source/browse/trunk/include/rapidjson/document.h

Comment: ok, @Haatschii was right. I was deleting `char*` too early. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was deallocating `buf` too early. I supposed that the parser will make a copy of the input, which was obviously wrong.

Comment: I do not get it. you deallocated buf in the last line, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
buf[json.size()] = '\0';
```

isn't this supposed to be:

```
buf[str.size()] = '\0';
```

?

Comment: No, buf[json.size()] = '\0'; should be correct. Array starts counting at 0.

Comment: buf[str.size() +1 ] is a buffer overflow

Comment: If so, it should be `buf[str.size()] = '\0'` since arrays index from 0.